# CloudSQL suddenly changes root password

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

So just recently I started using CloudSQL with an AppEngine instance. I got it working fine. The only thing it did was have one call that stored stuff in a table and one that outputted the content of the table.

All the suddenly when I accesed the page that should output the content of the table it said:

`Sorry, unexpected error: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")`

I couldn't understand what I did wrong, so what I did was to login, change the password for root@localhost to empty (as it can only be accessed from the GAE anyway) and it started working again, so ofcourse I thought it was my mistake.

The same thing is happening over and over again, makes it impossible to do anything. I set the password for root@localhost to empty, it works, then after a while it stops working.

The AppEngine Instance is in the same project as the CloudSQL DB and I connect to it over a unix socket (using Python, exactly as the example code does). And it works for a while but for some reason stops working after a while.

What am I doing wrong or is it just buggy?

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification questions: 1) are you connecting using the Unix sockets using the /cloudsql host? 2) Is the App Engine instance in the same of a different project than the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: I added some clarification to that to the post (1. yes, 2. same project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run FLUSH PRIVILEGES after you change the password.

Comment: I changed the password via the Google Developer Console so you'd think they do what ever is needed. And when I tried a flush after I changed the password via the Dev Console the password immediately stopped working.

Comment: I did all the password changing via the mysql command line utility now. I'll know in an hour or so if it has magically changed the password to something else.

Comment: You know, I got it working, when I changed the passwords from the mysql console (changed all except root@localhost to something and left the root@local to ""), did a flush, then it started working (still running after one night). This would mean the dev console is buggy(?) as you'd imagine it would work as well.